# Tag synonym request: type-coercion

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process

I'm seeing a lot of questions along these lines:

- [Converting String to int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java?s=1|5.5261) (Java)
- [convert double to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181942/convert-double-to-int?s=3|3.3093) (C#)
- [Cast float to int in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868424/cast-float-to-int-in-ocaml?s=2|3.5889) (OCaml)

These all involve converting/coercing types, but none of them use the current tag, `type-conversion`. I think that it would be a good idea to try and add tag synonyms to make it easier to find.

I suggest both `type-coercion` and `typecasting` as synonyms.